# css selector to retrieve nodes without any id

Tags: css-selectors

I only want to catch the first list item with a css selector.
That can i do?

```
<ul>
  <li class="someclass"> </li>
  <li id="thisId" class="someclass"> </li>
  <li id="thatId" class="someclass"> </li>
  <li id="someId" class="someclass"> </li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul li.someclass:first-child{

}
```